# Angular DxVectorMap SVG elements don't get refreshed when new data is loaded

Tags: typescript, angular5

I'm using Angular version of dxvectormaps and couldn't get the markers to redraw on vector maps when the data is changed. The new data is getting drawn along with previous data. When I look at the svg elements through browser developer options I see that there are bubble markers for both previous and new data. How to get the map to clear the old ones and re-draw new ones as per new data? Initially the map draws bubbles for the sum of all years. Then when based on user input it should show data for the selected year only replacing previous bubbles on the map. Following is the sample code

In the angular component file: mapComponent.ts

```
     import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
        import {Feature, FeatureCollection} from '../../../../models/util_classes.model';
        import {MapData1Service} from '../../../../data/map-data1.service';
        import * as maps from 'devextreme/dist/js/vectormap-data/world.js';
        import {DxVectorMapComponent} from 'devextreme-angular';



   export class mapComponent implements OnInit {
        @ViewChild('myVectorMap') bubbleMap: DxVectorMapComponent;

      public mapMarkerData: FeatureCollection;
      public slicedData: FeatureCollection;

      constructor(public mapDataService1: MapData1Service) {
        this.getMapData();
      }

    //Initially get the data from service 

    getMapData(){
        this.mapDataService1.geoMarkersEmit.subscribe(
          (mapData) => this.extractGeoMarkers(mapData));
      }

      //This is invoked when a user clicks a button to get a slice of the data used above
      getSlicedMapData(){
        this.mapDataService1.timeDataSetEmit.subscribe(
          (mapData) => this.extractMasterDataSet(mapData) );
      }

    //Draws the bubbles in the map initially
      extractGeoMarkers(mData: any){
        this.mapMarkerData = mData;
        this.bubbleMap.instance.option('layers[1].dataSource', this.mapMarkerData);
        this.bubbleMap.instance.option('layers[1].color', '#0f74a8');
      }



    //When user clicks a button slice of the data is loaded into a new FeatureCollection object and assigns
    // it to the dataSource of the datalayer. But this draws both bubbles from previous dataset as well as the 
    // newly assigned dataset 

    slicedGeoMarkers(mData: any){
        let markerLayer = this.bubbleMap.instance.getLayerByName('bubbles');

        this.slicedData = null;
        this.slicedData = mData;

        //this.bubbleLayer.instance.option('layers[1].dataSource', this.slicedData);
        //this.bubbleLayer.instance.option('layers[1].color', '#ffd70b');

        //this.bubbleMap.instance.getLayerByName('bubbles').getDataSource().dispose();

        this.bubbleMap.instance.option('layers[1].dataSource', this.slicedData);
        this.bubbleMap.instance.option('layers[1].color', '#ffd70b');

        //this.bubbleMap.instance.getLayerByName('bubbles').getDataSource().load();
        //this.bubbleMap.instance.getLayerByName('bubbles').getDataSource().reload();


        this.bubbleMap.instance.render();

    }
```

HTML file: mapComponent.html
[dataSource] and [color] parameters are not set under the `<dxi-layer #myDataLayer>` tag as it's set in the typescript code above.

```
<dx-vector-map
  #myVectorMap
  id="vector-map"
  size="{height:300, width:400}"
  [bounds]="[-144, 80, 170, -60]"
  [center]="{ lat: 40.749825, lng: -73.987963 }">
  <dxo-control-bar
    [enabled]="true"
    [opacity]="0.01"
    [color]="'#D8BFD8'"
    [borderColor]="'#6d6b77'">
  </dxo-control-bar>
  <dxo-tooltip
    [enabled]="true"
    [customizeTooltip]="customizeTooltip">
  </dxo-tooltip>
  <dxo-background
    [borderColor]="'#ffffff'">
  </dxo-background>
  <dxi-layer
    [dataSource]="worldMap"
    [hoverEnabled]="true"
    name="areas"
    [color]="'#d3dfd4'">
    <dxo-label
      [enabled]="true"
      dataField="name"
      [visible]="true">32
    </dxo-label>
  </dxi-layer>
  <dxi-layer #myDataLayer
    [minSize]="2"
    [maxSize]="20"
    [sizeGroups]="[0, 999, 99999, 99999999, 999999999999]"
    name="bubbles"
    elementType="bubble"
    [hoveredColor]="'rgba(255, 194, 21, 0.8)'"
    [hoveredBorderColor]="'#341453'"
    dataField="value">
  </dxi-layer>
  <dxi-legend markerShape="circle" [customizeText]="customizeText" verticalAlignment="top" size="10">
    <dxo-source layer="bubbles" grouping="size"></dxo-source>
  </dxi-legend>
</dx-vector-map>
```

Please help me how to get the map to show the new bubbles when the dataset is getting changed. Please answer in Angular5 Typescript as I'm not familiar with  JS or jQuery.

Many thanks

Comment: Kindly appreciate if a valid answer can be provided to the question, instead of making corrections to spelling mistakes or word phrases please